# Можно ли писать «никому ненужный» вместо «никому не нужный»?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

В текстах часто встречается слитное написание «никому не нужный», хотя правилами рекомендуется раздельное написание НЕ, например: клуб никому ненужных людей, одно из никому ненужный творений. Считается, что здесь усиление отрицания, но мне такое решение кажется формальным. 
   Для примера:  (1) нисколько не нужный – это, действительно, усиление отрицания признака, но: (2) ненужный людям, не нужный никому – здесь, скорее, область определения признака. Может быть, не стоит настаивать на только раздельном написании «никому не  нужный»?

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ.
 Спасибо за интересные примеры. Но вот что, по-моему, важно. Если Вы хотите выразить свою мысль так, чтобы другие вас поняли, надо соблюдать всем понятные правила для ее выражения.  Вы же не можете разговаривать только сам с собой (смайлик). А если какое-то правило кажется вам надуманным или неправильным, нужно быть готовым к тому, чтобы защитить свое мнение, в том числе форму своего письма.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ 2

1. Я за то, чтобы мы писали по «правильным» правилам. Большинство правил, которыми мы пользуемся, можно объяснить (хотя их никто не объясняет, что не очень хорошо).
2. Как объяснить это правило? Мы считаем, что перед нами  отрицательная синтаксическая конструкция, которую можно назвать усилительной, по аналогии с выражением отнюдь не нужный, отнюдь не интересный, далеко не новый. Но выражения ДАЛЕКО НЕ, ОТНЮДЬ НЕ включают наречия, которые,  действительно, усиливают  отрицательное значение прилагательного.
3. Мы же  к этим выражениям  автоматически добавляем отрицательные местоименные наречия НИКАК НЕ, НИСКОЛЬКО  НЕ, а также отрицательные местоименные существительные  НИКОМУ НЕ, НИЧЕМ НЕ.  И вопрос состоит в том, то именно МЕСТОИМЕННЫЕ СУЩЕСТВИТЕЛЬНЫЕ  обозначают не признак наречия, а область определения признака, поэтому их отнесенность к усилительным конструкциям неочевидна.
4. Например: нерастворимое в воде вещество,  ни в чем  НЕ растворимое вещество – это термины, странно   в них использовать  отрицательную конструкцию "НЕ+ растворимый". А если слово не употребляется без  НЕ, то мы спокойно пишем  его слитно:  никем непобедимый народ, то есть прецедент таких написаний имеется.
5. Народ чувствует всё это интуитивно, поэтому пишет «никому ненужный», считая это  усилением «ненужности», а не отрицанием «нужности».  Также они чаще пишут «никому неинтересный», но «нисколько не интересный», различая их значения.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ 3.
Ваша математика очень интересна, обязательно подумаю над ее содержанием. Если будут вопросы, то задам их Вам по возможности.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ 4 (почему "никому ненужный" имеет право на существование)

1. Выражения «ненужный» и «не нужный» тождественны по смыслу, поэтому отрицательная форма «не нужный» встречается редко, например при противопоставлении: не нужная, а совершенно бесполезная вещь.
2. Реально мы работаем со словами «нужный – ненужный», в частности, их значения можно усилить: очень нужный – абсолютно ненужный. Даже выражение «нисколько не нужный» имеет тот же смысл, что «абсолютно ненужный», и воспринимается  как чисто формальная и чужеродная запись.
3. Что касается области   определения слов  «нужный – ненужный», то здесь вообще нет отрицания: мы говорим только  о нужности или ненужности: нужный кому-то – ненужный никому.
4. Поэтому когда мы пишем НЕ раздельно, соблюдая формальное правило, получается, что форма правит смыслом, а это не нравится пользователям языка.
5. Правила должны быть правильными, а не субъективными, тогда они будут пониматься и соблюдаться людьми. Любое правило – это не «священная корова», общество имеет право обсудить то, что вызывает сомнение.
6. Понаблюдайте за текстами в Интернете - слитное написание подобных слов встречается чаще, при этом нельзя сказать, что они написаны неграмотными людьми. Например, со словами «зависимый – независимый» та же история. А вот  запись у Ожегова в его словаре: «независимо ни от каких запретов», смотрится вполне нормально.
7. И еще пару слов о том, как создаются правила. Я думаю, что они не создаются никак, а всем правит грамматика. То, что мы считаем правилами, это всего лишь решенные орфографические задачи. В нашем случае при выборе формы написания НЕ важно доказать, приставкой или отрицательной частицей является НЕ, все  же остальные рассуждения из этого должны следовать. А вот наши «готовые» правила не ко всем случаям подходят и не всегда работают. Я с большим уважением отношусь к орфографическому своду 1956 года. Но эти люди не могли сделать за нас всё - думаю, они надеялись, что мы поймем их общие идеи и сможем развивать их и применять творчески, а не цепляться строго за каждую букву.
8. По поводу  сообщения «Слитно писал бы в редких случаях, только для характеристики предметов: ненужные вещи, ненужные хлопоты... и т. п. В примерах никому не нужный, не нужный людям, совсем не нужный вижу строгое отрицание, а потому — в естественном понимании — сугубо раздельно без какой-либо дерзости». 
      К моему большому сожалению, не могу согласиться почти ни с чем. В частности, хотелось бы понять, почему «не нужный людям» пишется раздельно, здесь-то точно не усилительная конструкция.

Comment: Одному покажется надуманным это, другому - другое. Не заметим, как и правил не останется, а письмо станет многовариантным, а значит - плохо понятным.

Comment: София:
>И вопрос состоит в том, то именно МЕСТОИМЕННЫЕ СУЩЕСТВИТЕЛЬНЫЕ обозначают не признак наречия, а область определения признака, поэтому их отнесенность к усилительным конструкциям неочевидна.

О-о, "Обл. Определ." — очень знакомая и приятная категория для *технаря*. Если вначале ОО любого качества задана на множестве ВСЕ (всем НЕ), а затем выполнен переход к ОО НИКТО (никому НЕ), то как здесь не увидеть **усиления отрицания**? И вообще, метод нахождения экстремума по технологии обращения некоего параметра в 0 эффективнее перебора по *ансамблю*. Вот и здесь это срабатывает *интуитивно*.:

Comment: Что первично, что вторично? Правило или написания? Всегда считала что сначала был накоплен фактический материал, потом выводились закономерности и правила. Так что с Софьей я согласна, пищущий чувствует, где отрицание, где нет. Я дальше нескладно буду выражаться, потому что все пока на уровне интуиции. Мне кажется, дело в восприятии значения слов, в  некоторой синонимичности слов: никому не нужный = всем ненужный

Answer (score 11):

Слитно писал бы в редких случаях, только для характеристики предметов: ненужные вещи, ненужные хлопоты... и т. п.
В примерах *никому не нужный*, *не нужный людям*, *совсем не нужный* вижу строгое отрицание, а потому — в естественном понимании — сугубо раздельно без какой-либо дерзости.

Comment: Есди что, 
Бегемотуса в этой теме до сего момента не было.
Навскидку ответ Hermit'а мне нравится.
Возможно там и есть какие-то шероховатости на предмет соответствия букве правил, но не хочу копать. Думаю, тут есть люди, которые сделают это быстрее и лучше меня.

Comment: ![Слепые ведут слепых](http://artgalleryenc.com/Gallery/GetImage?file=Image_20120920020025859_158151d5-fa10-4896-bba5-f2bb27405158.JPEG&type=default)  
*Попадание в десяточку*, прикольно)))

Answer (score 9):

Если кто-то раньше меня высказал мнение, и я с ним согласна - зачем писать? Я поставила плюс, этого достаточно. Поэтому слышать о какой-то боязни - смешно.

Дальше по сути. Речь идет о прилагательных. На самом деле правило короткое и ОЧЕНЬ простое. **Приставка НЕ придает противоположное значение и пишется слитно. Частица НЕ - отрицательная. Пишется раздельно**. Всё. **Все остальное - это НЕ правило, это методические приёмы, помогающие отличить приставку, образующую новое слово с противоположным значением, от отрицательной частицы.** Когда-то (в "доЕГЭшную" пору) приходилось работать на подготовительных курсах в университет. На краткосрочных курсах времени мало - правил много. Приходилось компоновать, обобщать. Так вот, все многообразие приемов можно свести к одному известному: к проверке синонимом. Есть синоним или близкое по смыслу выражение - пиши слитно. Нет синонима, есть отрицание - пиши раздельно. Ненужный - это лишний. Никому лишний? Замена невозможна, пиши раздельно. Знаю, при желании вы можете найти слова, к которым синоним не подберешь. Но. повторяю, это только приём, поэтому  для меня достаточно, что я чувствую, что такое слово, выражение есть. Остальное в правилах - про слова "вовсе НЕ", "ничуть НЕ", отрицательные местоимения и даже про противопоставление - это приемы, помогающие отличить утвердительное значение от отрицательного. К*ак сказано у Розенталя, приставка НЕ утверждает наличие противоположного признака, частица НЕ отрицает наличие признака.*

Ничто из сказанного не противоречит ответу Hermit (и наоборот), почему же я не могу поставить плюс? ответ лаконичный, но верный.

Comment: Ларf - +1 по всем позициям.  
Все что могу добавить по комменту Дерзкого:  
Он неверно трактует Розенталя. Во-первых там "как правило", а во-вторых, "пояснительное слово" весьма размытое понятие. 
Нельзя на нем строить императивное правило. То что приводит Дерзкий - некая "запоминалка", вспомогательный признак для облегчения понимания и усвоения соьственно правила. Каковое и дает Ларf в полном объеме.   
Дальше - все у Ларf.

Answer (score 3):

Нужный --это качественное прилагательное.Относительные и притяжательные прилагательные пишутся раздельно с "не" : не деревянная скамейка, не птичий гомон.

Качественное прилагательное "нужный" с частицей "не" пишется вместе,кроме следующих случаев:

1) есть противопоставление : не нужная, а обязательная

2)в контексте есть отрицательное местоимение или отрицательное местоименное наречие:никому не нужная, нигде не нужная.

Если есть зависимые слова к этому прилагательному, это,в отличие от причастия, не влияет на написание прилагательного с "не", то есть пишем все равно слитно: нам ненужная вещь, девочке ненужный бант.

Answer (score 3):

Никому не нужный (наличие пояснительного слова "никому"). Просто ненужный (обозначение степени качества). Или я что-то путаю?!

Comment: Просто ненужный - это частица ПРОСТО, усиливающая значение прилагательного НЕНУЖНЫЙ. Наличие пояснительного слова - это всего лишь наличие  слова "никому", грамматическая роль которого здесь обсуждается. Непонятно, как два этих мало связанных между собой сообщения решают поставленный вопрос?

Answer (score 0):

К п. 3 **"Что касается области определения слов «нужный – ненужный», то здесь вообще нет отрицания: мы говорим только о нужности или ненужности: нужный кому-то – ненужный никому".**

А "нужный никому" - это утверждение или отрицание? По-моему, все-таки отрицание. Добавляем "не" и получаем усиление отрицания. Никому не нужный - это тот, который никому не нужен, а не тот, который "никому лишний".